# Window 10 not showing Ubuntu installed partitions on harddisk - Also not showing boot to Ubuntu options

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, windows-7

My laptop came with an SSD with Window 10 on it, and I extended that storage using a hard disk from a laptop which had Ubuntu installed.  Some partitions of that hard disk are NTFS and those filesystems were visible in Windows, but the one with the Linux on it were not readable but visible to diskmanager.

Also Windows is not showing the boot option for that Ubuntu based harddrive.

Can any one help me on this problem please.....

[image: I tried repairing the grub but this came up not sure what it wants from me and how to do that either]

Comment: By default, Ubuntu uses a filesystem called ext4. Windows can't read ext4 partitions. It can detect that they exist, but it can't read the data on them. Can you boot to Ubuntu in the boot manager?

Comment: no, i m unable to boot to it, there's no boot menu at all and i even tried to select an uefi file as trusted in bios but inside it there was no ubuntu named thing at all, so all in vain, one thing tough i was able to tap in to ubuntu via a bootable  pendrive and there i was able to see all my partitions of the harddisk along with the place the ubuntu was preinstalled. I Hope this info helps somehow thanks

Comment: What brand/model system? You mention trusted, is this an Acer which often requires you to change "unknown" to ubuntu or whatever you want. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Just boot from the USB-stick you used to install Ubuntu, and reinstall grub(2). Then go to the terminal and run ```sudo update-grub``` to be sure it is up to date. Than shutdown, remove usb, and startup again. Now you should see the grub-menu.

Comment: @JoepieEs yeah I tried repairing it using boot repair not sure if you meant same, but it did show me some warning which I posted inthe question .

Comment: ```Boot Repair``` is not the same as reinstall ```grub```. Go to the terminal and type ```sudo apt install grub```, it will then ask you for your password, type it in (it will not show your password or asterisks). Another thing is disable ```fastboot``` in ```Windows```. When you installed Ubuntu did you do that with ```Secure Boot``` enabled or disabled. If you installed it with ```Secure Boot ``` disabled, you have to keep the setting like that in your ```UEFI``` (what some people still call ```BIOS```). Check these things and let me know.

Comment: Thank you all for being there to help. I want to tell everyone that what I did was I formatted that hard drive and installed a fresh Ubuntu on it with some technicalities issues which I searched and solved I was able to run it successfully in my machine along with windows. I don't know to to cancel the question asked but anyways. Thanks